# How to know new row id will be inserted mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
id     path
1      image-1.jpg
2      image-2.jpg
5      image-5.jpg
9      image-9.jpg
```

I have deleted many last inserted row, I want to know the next increase id exactly will be inserted to set the path right like above!

Comment: on very first time insert the data path as null and get the Id . after that you can update that specific row.

Answer (score 0):

You should achieve this in 2 steps.

- insert a record with path = '' and increment ID will be inserted
- in second step, get last inserted ID and then make path and update to that id.